# Kentico Repeater with Custom Query

Tags: kentico

OK Here we go. 
Using Kentico 11/Portal Engine (no hot fixes)
Have a table that holds Content only page Types. One field of importance is a Date and time field.
I am trying to get rows out of this table that match a certain month and year criteria.  For instance give me all records where `Month=2 and Year=2018`. These argument will be passed via the query string
I have a custom Stored proc that I would like to receive two int(or string) arguments then return a collection of all matching rows.
[image]

I am using a RepeaterWithCustomQuery to call the procedure and handle the resulting rows. As you can see below the querystring arguments are named "year" and "monthnumber".
[image]
The Query

> Me.PR.PREDetailSelect
>   [image]
>   When my Webpart is set up in this configuration I get the following error:
>   [image]
>   In my Query, I have tried:

```
EXEC Proc_Custom_PRDetails @MonthNumber = ##ORDERBY##; @Year = ##WHERE##<br/>
EXEC Proc_Custom_PRDetails @MonthNumber = ##ORDERBY##, @Year = ##WHERE##<br/>
EXEC Proc_Custom_PRDetails @MonthNumber = ##ORDERBY## @Year = ##WHERE##<br/>
```

Any help would be appreciated (Thanks in advance Brendan). Lastly, don't get too caught up in the names of specific objects as I tried to change names to protect the innocent.

Comment: "Thanks in advance Brendan" < nice :)

Comment: The query `EXEC Proc_Custom_PRDetails @MonthNumber = ##ORDERBY##, @Year = ##WHERE##` looks right, but the confusing thing is the extra '=1' at the end in the error message.  Can you post an example of the query string?

Comment: Make sure to sanitize the macros used in the repeater's properties using data conversion methods: https://docs.kentico.com/k11/macro-expressions/reference-macro-methods#Reference-Macromethods-Dataconversion. Otherwise, you might introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities by directly passing user-controlled data into SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those [macros for queries](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/loading-data-using-custom-queries#Loadingdatausingcustomqueries-Usingpropertiestomodifyqueries) are not meant to be used with stor procs. The system generates this false condition 1=1 in case if you don't pass anything so it won't break the sql statement like the one below:

```
SELECT ##TOPN## ##COLUMNS##
FROM View_CMS_Tree_Joined AS V
INNER JOIN CONTENT_MenuItem AS C
ON V.DocumentForeignKeyValue = C.MenuItemID AND V.ClassName = N'CMS.MenuItem'
WHERE ##WHERE##
ORDER BY ##ORDERBY##
```

You need to convert you stor proc to SQL statement then you can use these *SQL macros* or use stor proc without parameters

If look at the query above *top* and *where* are not good because system will do adjustment, but you can use *order by*  and *columns*, but they both must be present (I think it passes them as is):

```
exec proc_test ##ORDERBY##, ##COLUMNS##
```

Honestly I would advice against doing this, plus you won't gain much by calling stor proc.

Comment: Well, the whole idea behind a stored proc is being able to use SQL functions (not sure if I can use those in Kentico, like Month() and Year()).  Anyhow, it does not appear like this works.

Error while evaluating expression: QueryString.GetValue("year", 2018) = @Year |(identity)GlobalAdministrator|(hash)ec15e695c31e0bd693eb5ffb9df7a1639ff66ba83d782dd248db1986abf9bbc6

Comment: Ahem make sure that you can call your stored  proc in SQL:  
exec proc_test @param1= 1, @param2 = 5 and it works.

Comment: here is a couple screenshots http://prntscr.com/k78g9m and http://prntscr.com/k78gmb

Comment: Thanks Peter, appreciate the help. I ended up using this: SELECT ##COLUMNS## FROM proc_test  WHERE ##WHERE##.  I did not have any arguments in the Selected columns filter but the Where condition contained: Year(DateTime) = {?year|(default)2018?} AND Month(DateTime) = {?month|(default)7?} AND [Approved]=1 .