# Executing a stored procedure using a Repeater with custom query in Kentico

Tags: stored-procedures, repeater, kentico

I am trying to call a stored procedure that takes in 3 inputs (State, Zip, & Distance). Upon submit of the search the values inputted will be put in the query string which is how I am trying to get them to pass to the stored procedure.

I decided to use a repeater with a custom query, which in my Query I have set up like this:

```
exec Republic.BranchesNearZip @zip = '{%zipCode%}', @state = '{%state%}', @miles = '{%distance%}'
```

with a transformation.

When I check my inspector I see the values in the response, but I keep getting, 'No Data Found', but If I were to hard code the values into the custom query it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work with macros like {% ... %} out of the box, this was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333571/kentico-repeater-with-custom-query/51334394#51334394). You need to use sql query and [sql macros](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/loading-data-using-custom-queries#Loadingdatausingcustomqueries-Usingpropertiestomodifyqueries), you *can't use stor proc with parameters*.

Comment: OMG thanks for this I saw this article and accidentally closed it out and could not find it again.

Comment: So I checked out that article and see the screen shots your posted. I see those values are hard coded into the WHERE clause and the ORDER BY. What if I had multiple parameters that I'd be getting from my query string that needed to be set in the WHERE clause. For instance the zip, state, and distance.

Comment: Yeah but it is some sort of a hacking... You are not really winning anything here, plus it makes it a bit unclear. Teroretically you can do:
exec Republic.BranchesNearZip ##WHERE## and then put into where text box:

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use macros in the query itself. However, you can still pass the macros to the query and pass them to your stored procedure.

Use the following query as an example (NOTE: Make sure the query type is "Query text"):

```
DECLARE @NumOne int,
        @NumTwo int;

SELECT ##COLUMNS##

EXEC [dbo].[spAddTwoNumbers] @NumOne, @NumTwo
```

Then in the `Select columns` attribute of our repeater:

```
@NumOne = {% return 25 %}, @NumTwo = {% return 25 %}
```

The query parser will produce the following query as a result:

```
DECLARE @NumOne int,
        @NumTwo int;

SELECT @NumOne = 25, @NumTwo = 25

EXEC [dbo].[spAddTwoNumbers] @NumOne, @NumTwo
```